# How to disable a Datefield and Timefield in GXT?

Tags: gxt

I have a added the datefield and timefield in ToolBar in my project. How to disable datefield in GXT.

Answer (score 2):

Just use method disable;

```
dateField.disable();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `dateField.setReadOnly(true);`